# Powershell - Function to retrieve all items from a list

Tags: list, powershell

I'm just getting started with Powershell and am trying to write a reusable script that lets me get all items from an arbitrary list:

```
function Get-SPItems
{
<# 
    .SYNOPSIS  
        Get all Items from a Sharepoint List
    .PARAMETER list
        Which List to get items from
    .PARAMETER source
        Optional Sharepoint Source
    .EXAMPLE 
     Send-WOL -list Hosts
#>

    param(
        [string]$list,
        [string]$source = "https://mysite.com"
    )

    # grab snapin
    if ((Get-PSSnapin | Where {$_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"}) -eq $null) {
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
    }

    $spSourceWeb = Get-SPWeb $source
    $list = $spSourceWeb.Lists[$list]

    return $list.GetItems()

}
```

I want to be able to call this function from any other script, such as:

```
. .\Get-SPList.ps1

$items = Get-SPList -list "MyList"

foreach ($item in $item) {
    Write-Host $item["ID"]
}
```

This is not working how I want it, unfortunately execution of the below script yields this error:

> Get-SPList : The term 'Get-SPList' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Both files are in the same directory, which is also the working directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method is not called `Get-SPList` but `Get-SPItems`

So,

```
$items = Get-SPItems -list "MyList"

foreach ($item in $item) {
    Write-Host $item["ID"]
}
```

Comment: I think you missed to attach the error? :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using PowerShell ISE 64bit.

Below code should be executed before your script:-

```
#Check and add SharePoint PowerShell snap-in
if(-not(
Get-PSSnapin | Where { $_.Name -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"})
) {
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;
}
```

It basically is adding the snapping which contains the methods like Get-SPWeb..

Comment: Get-SPItems is his own custom function, and thus not loaded through the SnapIn. He does need it for Get-SPWeb and such, though.

Comment: corrected.. I was suggesting in general.